# How to run raw SQL query without any expected result in Laravel 6?

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

In Laravel 6.x is any way to run raw SQL query without any expected result?

Like this one:

```php
$query = 'INSERT INTO product_copys (SELECT '. implode(',', $myColumArray) .' FROM products)';
```

I tried this:

```php
DB::run($query);
```

...but it said `FatalThrowableError: Call to protected method Illuminate\Database\Connection::run() from context 'Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager'`.

Any idea?

Comment: You can try "DB::statement($query);" or "DB::select($query);"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you try DB::statement() ?

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO product_copys (SELECT '. implode(',', $myColumArray) .' FROM products)';

DB::statement($query);
```